# Can't see action tool bar on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: screenshot]

Everything was fine yesterday. But I opened a new Android Studio project and can't see the top action bar (With various button shortcuts). And I can't find an option to reenable it.

Need help ;_;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: O]

Go to **View -> Appearance** and check those specific toolbars are activated or not

Comment: I was checking the windows section to find the option to enable it and forgot that view option existed in menu bar. Thanks for the answer. It solved my issue.